# PSD to HTML IPhone 5 and chrome toolbar

Tags: html, css, psd

PSD to HTML IPhone 5 and chrome toolbar
Hello! 
I have a PSD with size of IPhone 5. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByriSFbUU1n_blFodHlMbEVvY28

I want to make pixel perfect PSD -> HTML.
I develop with Chrome Code inspector with Iphone 5 dimention
and it looks great: http://joxi.ru/v29QQ6Duw18K2G
But when I watch this on my IPhone 5 I see this - 
http://joxi.ru/BA0ddPOHXLLoAy

Link to code on my server - http://romangjx.bget.ru/test/vidjetinlinemobile1/build/

How can I solve this problem??

Comment: I think the problem here is the navigation bar is not counted in the emulator in Chrome dev-tools. But on a real iPhone, there is a nav bar which takes some of the available height.

Comment: thanks, that solved the problem, post is as an answer so I can confirm it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is the navigation bar is not counted in the emulator in Chrome dev-tools. But on a real iPhone, there is a nav bar which takes some of the available height.